# jquery offset behavior

Tags: jquery

When you do something like this:

```
var originalOffset = something.offset()
something.offset({top:0,left:0})
something.offset(originalOffset)
```

I would expect `something` to be in exactly the same position in the page afterwards.
Well, this is not the case in my context. What properties of `offset()` destroy this desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if the offset parent of the element is the document, but not always if the element is inside another element that is positioned.

The `offset` method returns the position relative to the document, you should try the `position` method instead, which returns the position relative to the offset parent.

Comment: Maybe I am too dumb but I cannot understand why this explains the behavior. If I set the offset of an element to exactly the same values it had before, how can it be moved to a different place?

Comment: @CaptainFim: Well, in most cases it work, and jQuery manages to calculate the positon to use. However, when you set the `offset` of the element, it also set the style `position:relative` on the element. If this changes the layout it can change the position of the offset parent. Thus, when you read the `offset` it will use the original offset parent position, but when you try to put it back, it will use the new offset parent position. The element ends up at the same place relative to the offset parent, but if the offset parent has moved, that is not the same postion in the page.